# send_from_directory in flask is not downloading images

Tags: python, flask

I followed [this tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/handling-file-uploads-with-flask) and everything works except for downloading the images that were uploaded. I get 404 errors for everything I try to display in the browser. I can see the images on the hard drive just fine, but they do not download on the /uploads route. ANy ideas?

```
@bp.route('/uploads/<filename>')
def upload(filename):
    print('path: '+str(current_app.config['PRODUCT_UPLOAD_PATH'])+', filename: '+filename)
    return send_from_directory(current_app.config['PRODUCT_UPLOAD_PATH'], filename)
```

Here is the html template that loads the files. The filenames popup proeprly, but the route just shows 404 errors for all the images.

```
                    {% for file in files %}
                      <img src="{{ url_for('main.upload', filename=file) }}" style="width: 64px">
                    {% endfor %}
```

config.py to show where the directories are pointing.

```
    MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH = 1024 * 1024
    UPLOAD_EXTENSIONS = ['.jpg', '.png', '.gif']
    PRODUCT_UPLOAD_PATH = 'uploads/products/'
```

Comment: can you show example urls which you use? If they have path with `/` then you may need `<filename:path>` because as default it may expect string without `/` and it may treats `/uploads/path/to/file` as different routing and it may not find it - so it gives error 404

Comment: did you run debug mode to see error details? Do you get any error message when you run it in console? We can't run it and without details we can't help you because we can't see what makes problem.

Comment: I fixed it by changing the configs to this: PRODUCT_UPLOAD_PATH = os.path.join(basedir, 'uploads', 'products') I am assuming this has something to do with the way strings/filepaths are treated.

Comment: probably it runs code in different folder and when it searchs relative path `uploads/products/` then it can't find it in this folder. Using `os.path.join(basedir, ...)` you create absolute path which is correct even if it runs code in different folder.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I found that makes this work. Thanks for the help from everyone!

```
import os
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

class Config(object):
    #This string does not work
    #PRODUCT_UPLOAD_PATH = 'uploads/products/'
    #This is the proper way to configure file paths
    PRODUCT_UPLOAD_PATH = os.path.join(basedir, 'uploads', 'products')
```